# Security of certain homomorphic encryption scheme

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, provable-security

Is the following homomorphic encryption scheme:

Ahmed El-Yahyaoui and Mohamed Dafir Ech-Chrif El Kettani, [*A Verifiable Fully Homomorphic Encryption Scheme for Cloud Computing Security*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06862) (April 2018, at [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06862))

known to be secure/vulnerable against certain attacks? It sounds a bit to good, to be true.

___________-

Comment: The main security argument boils down to _"Therefore, an adversary cannot then distinguish encryptions of units from encryptions of non-units. Consequently, the attack proposed on Li-Wang’s scheme [10] in [12] do not work for our case. Based on these assumptions, we believe that our fully homomorphic encryption scheme is indistinguishable under chosen ciphertext attacks"_; which is short of modern academic standards. That does not imply wrong.